# fitting vertically on a full screen img tag

Tags: jquery, css, supersized

I'm using the Supersized wordpress plugin to present a fullscreen slideshow on http://lorenzo.dentasignclients.com .

One thing that's bugging me, that when viewing in a portrait setting, the images stretch vertically, like so : [image: example]

Is there a hack I can implement to make sure that the image is full width and full height, but not stretched in portrait view?

I tried adding a media quite, and making the width and height auto. This accomplished the not stretching, but then the image is no longer the full width and height of the background.

```
#supersized img{
    background-color:white;
    width:auto!important;
    height:auto!important;
}
```

help much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know about this plugin, but a common practice is to use a background image in CSS and set the `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! This was a conflict caused by bootstrap.

The plugin is correctly handling the scaling of the images, but bootstrap prevents all images from going over 100%

i.e

```
    img {
    max-width:100%
    }
```

so, just update with

```
#supersized img {
   max-width:none;
}
```